CBS Authentication Expired - Azure Service bus
I am trying to add a simple message to a service bus locally. I have a c# project locally too in Visual Studio that works towards same ressource with no problems.
But in Visual Studio Code with Phython I cannot get it working:
First I login to azure with azd login successfully.
I have following script:
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential as cho

rith_servicebus_name = "xxx.servicebus.windows.net"
q_name = "xxx"
credential = cho()
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient(rith_servicebus_name , credential)
rith = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=q_name)
with rith:
    val = ServiceBusMessage("Hello Rithwik")
    rith.send_messages(val)

I get following error:

Exception has occurred: ServiceBusAuthenticationError CBS
Authentication Expired. Error condition: amqp:internal-error.
azure.servicebus._pyamqp.error.TokenExpired: Error condition:
ErrorCondition.InternalError  Error Description: CBS Authentication
Expired.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "C:\Development\PortHierarchyData\service-bus-tester.py", line
9, in 
with rith: azure.servicebus.exceptions.ServiceBusAuthenticationError: CBS
Authentication Expired. Error condition: amqp:internal-error.

When running the script it seems like its trying as some threads starts and closes, but then throws an error after around 10 seconds.
Any suggestions what can cause this or how to troubleshoot? Kind of strange as my visual studio project with .NET works fine, so its not network related.

The error 'CBS Authentication Expired' indicates that the credentials used for authentication with Azure Service Bus have expired or are invalid. Please provide the correct credentials and try again.

Try to run the code with Client credentials? **from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
tenant_id = "your-tenant-id"
client_id = "your-client-id"
client_secret = "your-client-secret"**

Check this link to fix the issue.

Make sure you have provided the correct DefaultAzureCredentials in the system environment variables.

Check the Azure Service Bus and it's Queue are available in Azure Portal or deleted?

@DasariKamali:  A missing or disabled namespace/entity would not cause an authentication error.  There are specific NotFound error codes mapped to that scenario.

@thomas-segato:  The error indicates that your credential could not be authenticated due to being past its valid time period.   You don't show us how the credential is created, but based on the error, it seems you'd need to refresh before using it.

The whole idea is to not use credentials for audit purposes etc.  So its important when I run locally its mine, and in azure the web app. The wierd thing is it works in my c# sample locally.

If you are still facing an issue with Default Credential, you can client credential way to make it work as an alternative:
Firstly, register an app and then create client secret in it:

Then give Access to Service bus using IAM give role, Azure Service Bus Data Sender  to the App created:

You can give name or object id:

Then use below code to send messages to service bus:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential as rith
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient as sbc, ServiceBusMessage as rith_sbm

ri_tn_id = "93296d"
ri_cl_id = "7ed04"
ri_cl_sct = "GEI8bzR"
servicebus_name = "nameofservicebus.servicebus.windows.net"
rith_q_name = "rithq"

ri_creds = rith(tenant_id=ri_tn_id, client_id=ri_cl_id, client_secret=ri_cl_sct)

ri_cl = sbc(servicebus_name, ri_creds)
with ri_cl.get_queue_sender(queue_name=rith_q_name) as ri:
    ri_out = rith_sbm("Hello Rith Bojja ")
    ri.send_messages(ri_out)

Output:

Or else you can use ServiceBusClient which uses connection string.
